# Fruit fly type bugs always appear in the kitchen when the weather heats up

Tags: pest-control

I have lived in my house for two springs/summers now and each time when the weather heats up it seems like the fruit fly type bugs just start spreading around the house like crazy, mostly from the kitchen. I have a regular pest control guy and he suggested pouring bleach down the drains. That, combined with a trap using apple cider vinegar seems to contain them sort of well, I have to pour the bleach down the drains on a regular basis and redo the trap as it fills up quickly. Also, I make sure to put away all food so it's not like I have a bunch of stuff out on the counters.

They obviously hang out/breed in the drains and my kitchen has a sink with two drains (really both meet up and go down the same pipe) and I don't have a garbage disposal.

Would a disposal help at all? Is there anything I can do to keep this from being a problem again? The weather is heating up again and I really don't want to deal with this another year.

Comment: Where do you live?  Are you sure they come from the drain?  Any time we have little flies like that its because a potato has fallen under something and started to rot.

Comment: Live in Texas, I am pretty sure they come from the drain because the bleach seems to kill them off pretty well. If I leave out a trap that will collect a bunch of them but without the bleach they just keep filling up the trap. It seems like they come back pretty quick post bleach though so I have to use it on a regular basis

Comment: We have had great success using these [cheap fruitfly traps](http://www.terro.com/terro-fruit-fly-trap-2-pack).  Apple Cider Vinegar attracts the flies nicely

Answer (score 1):

These small flies are very hard to keep out because they are so small, so I think looking for what is attracting them is a better long term solution.  This is a guess, but I think that using bleach in the drain is probably masking the scent of what is truly attracting them.  A small flying insect making it's way through a water-filled P-Trap under the sink is unlikely, and unless you also have a sewer smell coming from the sink, the P-trap is probably working correctly.

Look for dead portions of houseplants, fruit or veggies that have fallen behind a cabinet or the fridge or in the cracks next to the stove, etc.  Clean, clean, clean.  Pull out the stove and the fridge and clean.  Empty out the cabinet under the sink and clean that very well.  Pull out everything from the pantry and get rid of the expired stuff, and clean.

I'm in Texas as well and anytime we have had tiny little flies at our house or my mother in law's, its been from potatoes that were forgotten or something else that was leaking or rotting out of site that we didn't know about.

Comment: I don't necessarily think they are coming in from the sink but they live/breed down there for sure. The only place food could have fallen is by the fridge so I'll pull that out and give it a good cleaning, otherwise I keep all fruits/veggies in the fridge for this reason but I'll give the whole kitchen a good scrub down.